# Определить сходство данного mp3 файла с имеющимся в базе данных аудиофайлами

Tags: алгоритм, аудио, библиотеки, распознавание

Нужны библиотеки или примеры работы, в следующей теме:
Есть база данных с аудио файлами в mp3, на вход программы должен подаваться сторонний аудио файл в том же формате, программа должна пробегаться по файлам в базе, и возвращать(на екран в файл не важно куда) в процентах степень соответствия файлам которые находятся в базе. Например на вход подают

```
test.mp3
```

программа должна вернуть например

```
base1.mp3 сходство 50%
base2.mp3 сходство 20%
base3.mp3 сходство 30%
```

и так далее сходство должно определяться по содержимому файлов(как в программах поиска песни).

Со звуком никогда не работал даже не знаю с чего начать и как сделать, в интернете полно всякой сухой теории но как применить не понимаю, возможно есть библиотеки которые работают со звуком, и алгоритмы в которых данные библиотеки будут применяться для вывода степени соответствия.

Comment: Что вы под "сходством" понимаете? 1- К примеру, если я мелодию напою, то должна ли программа найти песню (с оригинальным исполнителем). 2- Что в base1.mp3, base2.mp3 итд хранится? Фиксированные команды типа hey, siri? Произвольный текст? Один известный диктор? 3- Шум хотите классифицировать? (птицы поют, грузовик проехал, собаки лают)

Comment: 1. Не должна, заранее известно что входной файл будет либо песня либо аудио дорожка с клипа.
2. в base1.mp3, base2.mp3 хранятся такие же песни или аудио дорожки полученные с клипа.
текст если можно то было бы здорово распознать, но пока просто нужно в процентах выводить процент соответствия как это проверить и не знаю, по длине не подходит так как например песни могут быть разные по длине

Comment: чтобы определить песню по содержимому, есть https://acoustid.org/ Для своей базы, можно [`acoustid.fingerprint_file()`](https://github.com/beetbox/pyacoustid) использовать, чтобы получить отпечатки для mp3.

Answer (score 1):

По мотивам [телеги на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/330988/) 2017 года

1. Переводм песенку в спектр. Для этого

- нарезаем на кусочки по 512 сэмплов (чем больше, тем точнее и медленнее),
- каждому кусочку делаем FFT
- находим модули значений FFT
- зеркальную половинку выбрасываем долой

Получаем 256 значений. Эти 256 значений рисуем вертикальной полоской пикселей, яркость пикселя определяется значением.

потом берем еще 256 сэмплов и делаем то же самое. Полоски пикселей клеим встык.

2. Получилась 2D ч/б картиночка, а алгоритмов сравнения картиночек можно найти вагон

- можно сравнивать нейросетями
- можно использовать feature-based методы типа SIFT/RANSAC

Answer (score 0):

А если получать амплитуду (уровни громкости) для каждого шага звукового потока, затем сравнивать эти значения для двух разных потоков?
То есть:

1. mp3 -> wav
2. получение уровней громкости в массив, например, так:

> ```
> __int64 Count = BASS_ChannelGetLength(stream, BASS_POS_BYTE);
>     Double PosMus(0.0);
>     Double LenMus = BASS_ChannelBytes2Seconds(stream, Count);
>     Double BytePos(0.0);    
> while(PosMus < LenMus) // пока не достигнем конца звучания
>     {
>         BytePos = BASS_ChannelSeconds2Bytes(stream, Pos); // позиция в байтах
>         BASS_ChannelSetPosition(stream, BytePos, BASS_POS_BYTE);
>         Нам нужно значение HIWORD(BASS_ChannelGetLevel(stream)) - вот его и берем в массив
>         PosMus += 0.01; //Шагаем по потоку с шагом 10 мс
>     }
> ```

3. сравнение двух массивов.

Конечно, в лоб сравнить не получится: нужно вводить нормирование по общему уровню громкости, сравнивать pitch, длительность и т.п.

Comment: Абсолютная громкость - не очень хорошо, громкость может различаться. Если только её изменение как-то смотреть.